# Extracting values from a string in R using regex

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to extract the first and second numbers of this string and store them in separate variables.

```
(User20,10.25)
```

I can't figure out how to get the user number and then his value.

What I have managed to do so far is this, but I don't know how to remove the rest of the string and get only the number.

```
gsub("\\(User", "", string)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
str1 <- '(User20,10.25)'
scan(text=gsub('[^0-9.-]+', ' ', str1),quiet=TRUE) 
#[1] 20.00 10.25
```

In case the string is

```
str2 <- '(User20-ht,-10.25)'
scan(text=gsub('-(?=[^0-9])|[^0-9.-]+', " ", str2, perl=TRUE), quiet=TRUE)
#[1]  20.00 -10.25
```

Or

```
library(stringr) 
str_extract_all(str1, '[0-9.-]+')[[1]]
#[1] "20"    "10.25"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '[0-9.-]+')[[1]]
#[1] "20"    "10.25"
```

Comment: The `scan` answer is nice, particularly because it has a numeric output.

Comment: Nice options. +1. The only change I would make (for both your answer and hwnd's) is to include the possibility of negative numbers (change `'[0-9.]+'` to `'[0-9.-]+'`).

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks, I always forget about the `-` numbers.

Answer (score 5):

[Tyler Rinker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000343/tyler-rinker)'s ["qdapRegex" package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapRegex/index.html) has some functions that are useful for this kind of stuff.

In this case, you would most likely be interested in `rm_number`:

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_number(x, extract = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "20"    "10.25"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strsplit` with `sub` ...

```
> sub('\\(User|\\)', '', strsplit(x, ',')[[1]])
[1] "20"    "10.25"
```

It would probably be easier to match the context that you want instead.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0-9.]+', x))[[1]]
[1] "20"    "10.25"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is one approach:

```
[^,\)\([A-Z]]
```